# Update addition depending to size array

Tags: matlab

I don't find a solution to this problem

In my initialization I define an array "R" with certain number of values (the boolean flag with have the same length too). Later in my code I do an addition with a boolean flag.

Do you have an idea how to "update" this addition without  editing it manually?

The part of the code i want to improve is

```
( (R(5)*B(i,5))+ (R(1)*B(i,1)) + (R(3)*B(i,3)) +(R(4)*B(i,4)) +(R(2)*B(i,2)) )
```

Thank you in advance for you answear

the code :

```
% i reflects the time
    
% bollean flag type double
B(1,:)=[0 0 0 0 0];
B(2,:)=[0 0 0 0 0];
B(3,:)=[0 0 0 0 1];
B(4,:)=[0 0 0 1 0];
B(5,:)=[0 0 0 1 1];
    
%info1
E(1)=0;
E(2)=0;
E(3)=10;
E(4)=20;
E(5)=40;
    
%info2
R = [1/30 1/30 1/30 1/30 1/30];
    
for i=1:5
    
    for k=1:5 
    
    
        if E(i)>0
    
            powerload_R2(i,k)=  (  ( R(k))/( (R(5)*B(i,5))+ (R(1)*B(i,1)) + (R(3)*B(i,3)) +(R(4)*B(i,4)) +(R(2)*B(i,2)) ) )  *B(i,k)*E(i)+0; % fonctionnel
        else
        powerload_R2(i,k)= 0;
        end
        
    end
        
end
    
'end'
```

results

```
%results
powerload_R2(i,k)=
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   10
0   0   0   20  0
0   0   0   20  20
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. The code runs and produces the mentioned result. What do you want to change here? Where does "updating a boolean addition" come in?

Comment: `(R(5)*B(i,5))+ (R(1)*B(i,1)) + (R(3)*B(i,3)) +(R(4)*B(i,4)) +(R(2)*B(i,2))` is the same as `sum(R.*B(i,:))`, for any size of R.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes @Adriaan and – @AnderBiguri, it is about the `(R(5)*B(i,5))+ (R(1)*B(i,1)) + (R(3)*B(i,3)) +(R(4)*B(i,4)) +(R(2)*B(i,2))`. I still have difficuties to understand how it works.  `sum(R.*B(i,:))` Does R. means that R number 1 will be attached to B1 and R2 will be attached to b number 2 ?

Comment: can I delete the  `for k=1:5 [...] end `  and the r(k) from the numerator By `powerload_R(i,:)=  (  ( R./( sum(R.*B(i,:) ) )  ) *B(i,k)*E(i)+0;` ? But  i would like to mention i still want i still want to  have  `powerload_R(i,1)` related to `R(i,1)/ sum(R.*B(i,:) )`

Comment: `R ./ sum(R .* B(i,:))`, besides, `+0` doesn't do anything of course. It looks like you'd be better served by [the MathWork's own basic MATLAB tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) though, rather than have random people on the internet write your code. This 5-step `for` loop is about as good and simple as it gets as an example on vectorisation.

Comment: yes of course `+0` mean anything i have forgotten to delete  this line. It will be used for a power load  `+0` will be use to record energy load. I will take your advice to get through the link you mentioned. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be greatly simplified. As @AnderBiguri has mentioned, this long line `(R(5)*B(i,5))+ (R(1)*B(i,1)) + (R(3)*B(i,3)) +(R(4)*B(i,4)) +(R(2)*B(i,2))` is just the sum of the product of `R` elements with the corresponding elements of the ith row of `B`, or simply `dot(R,B(i,:))`.

Also you can initialize `powerload_R2 = zeros(5)` and alter only those rows corresponding to `E > 0`. This way, you only have to iterate `find(E > 0)` times over the rows of `powerload_R2` and you don't need the inner `k` loop. That said, loops are not as evil these days as they used to be on the early years of MATLAB, so use the most natural way to write your algorithm before thinking about vectorization for speed.

```
% i reflects the time
% boolean flag type double
B = [0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 1
     0 0 0 1 0
     0 0 0 1 1];
% info1
E = [0 0 10 20 40];

% info2
R(1:5) = 1/30;

powerload_R2 = zeros(5);

for i = find(E > 0)
    powerload_R2(i,:) = R ./ dot(R,B(i,:)) .* B(i,:)*E(i); % fonctionnel
end
```

Comment: thank you for your input. I will take into consideration your answer tomorrow. thnank you for the formulation of `E R ` I am not yet use too about`powerload_R2(i,:) = R ./ dot(R,B(i,:)) .* B(i,:)*E(i);`that each colonn will be done individualy here for each data set (`powerload_R2(i,1)`with `R1` `powerload_R2(i,2)` with `R2`...)

Comment: Currently in my code B will me "updated" after each  `i`or"periode of time" to give the same amount of energy periode after period with B with more and less data set activated depending the value of E. I need to think about your code

Comment: i should have mentioned `E(i,1)`. My mistake